# GWT: How to center element containing CellTable?

Tags: gwt, gwt-2.2-celltable

I'm trying to center an element that contains a `CellTable`. The actual 
centering logic works okay, but I'm having problems with all those 
attaching/detaching events. Basically, I'm doing this in my container 
widget:

```
@Override
public void onLoad() {
  super.onLoad();
  center();
}
```

However, it seems that `onLoad` on the container does not mean that all 
children have loaded, so... the actual centering routine is called too 
early and `Element.getOffsetWidth`/`getOffsetHeight` are both returning `0`.
This results in the container being displayed with the left upper corner 
in the center of the screen.

Same thing happens if I use an `AttachEvent.Handler` on the `CellTable`.

So... is there any event on `CellTable`, or on `Widget` or whatever that 
allows me to trigger an action when the DOM subtree has been attached to 
the DOM?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [scheduleDeferred](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.0/com/google/gwt/core/client/Scheduler.html#scheduleDeferred%28com.google.gwt.core.client.Scheduler.ScheduledCommand%29). A deferred command is executed after the browser event loop returns.

```
Scheduler.get().scheduleDeferred(new ScheduledCommand() {
    @Override
    public void execute() {
        center();
    }
});
```

Comment: It seems to work, but what are the chances that this command would be execute *before* the command used internally by CellTable to render the rows? I'm asking because it uses `scheduleFinally`, and to be honest, I haven't yet understand all this variety of scheduling.

Comment: None, unless CellTable schedules other deferred commands to render the rows. Here is a useful answer about Scheduler methods. [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5131086/using-the-gwt-scheduler](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5131086/using-the-gwt-scheduler).

Answer (score 1):

Override `onAttach` instead of `onLoad`. `onAttach` default implementation calls `onLoad` followed by `doAttachChildren` (which calls `onAttach` on each child widget), so the following code should call `center` after the children have been attached:

```java
@Override
public void onAttach() {
  super.onAttach();
  center();
}
```

(BTW, the default implementation of `onLoad` is a no-op)

Comment: Doesn't work because the table data is rendered using `Scheduler.scheduleFinally` inside `HasDataPresenter.ensurePendingState()`. However, `HasDataPresenter.resolvePendingState` does the real work, and it seems this can be invoked indirectly using `CellTable.getRowElement` which calls `HasDataPresenter.flush` and then `HasDataPresenter.resolvePendingState`.

Comment: Quite hacky IMHO, but it seems the only way to force rendering on the `CellTable`. An alternative solution, cleaner, would have been to listen for the `LOADED` event using `AbstractHasData.addLoadingStateChangeHandler`. Unfortunately, the `LOADED` event is triggered before the rendering is performed.