# GWT: Timer and Scheduler Classes

Tags: java, gwt, scheduler

I have read [this page](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsDelayed) over several times, and am just not seeing some of the inherent differences between GWT's `Timer` and `Scheduler` classes. I'm looking for the use cases and applicability of each of the following:

- `Timer`, `Timer::schedule` and `Timer::scheduleRepeating`
- `Scheduler::scheduleDeferred`
- `Scheduler::scheduleIncremental`
- `IncrementalCommand`
- `DeferredCommand`

These all appear to be doing the same thing, more or less, and it feels like you can accomplish the same objectives with all of them. Is this just GWT's way a providing multiple ways of doing the same thing? If not, please help me understand when and where each is appropriately used.

Comment: check out [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5132382/547020).

Comment: This question addresses the `Scheduler`, but not the `Timer`, and does not compare when it is appropriate to use one vs. the other.

Comment: @IAmYourFaja Still your question seems a bit broad. Perhaps focus on one problem at time.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Use **Scheduler** when you need a browser to complete whatever it is currently doing before you   tell it to do something else. For example:

```
myDialogBox.show();
Scheduler.get().scheduleDeferred(new ScheduledCommand() {

    @Override
    public void execute() {
        myTextBox.setFocus();
    }
});
```

In this example, focus will not be set until the browser completes rendering of the dialog, so you tell the program to wait until the browser is ready.

Use **Timer** if you want some action to happen after a specified period of time. For example:

```
 notificationPanel.show();
 Timer timer = new Timer() {
     @Override
     public void run() {
         notificationPanel.hide();
     }
 };
 timer.schedule(10000);
```

This code will show notificationPanel, and then it will hide it after 10 seconds.

Answer (score 12):

As the JavaDoc says, `DeferredCommand` is deprecated in favor of `Scheduler`.
The problem with `DeferredCommand` and `IncrementalCommand` is that they have a static state (which makes it hard to use reliably in tests). Moreover, their (static) methods make JSNI calls which forces you to use a `GWTTestCase` to test your code (static methods aren't –easily– mockable). Static methods also make it impossible to wrap them (to, e.g. add some logging or whatever).
On the other hand, you work with an instance of a `Scheduler` (if you want testable code, you'll use dependency-injection to get a instance of a scheduler and will never call `Scheduler.get()` except in your DI "factory"). In a test, you can then use a `StubScheduler` for instance.

Then there's `Timer`, which is similar to the others but the scheduled task can be cancelled. Note that `Timer` makes use of JSNI too, just like `DeferredCommand`; any kind of code that uses a `Timer` will need a `GWTTestCase` to be unit-tested.