# D3 Chart grows but won't shrink inside a flex div

Tags: css, d3.js, flexbox

A similar problem here: [GWT Google Charts grow but don't shrink](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38249689/gwt-google-charts-grow-but-dont-shrink)

I have a d3 chart that is set to be responsive. If it's inside a flexbox layout, it will grow, but will not shrink. See the code in this codepen:

https://codepen.io/bentedder/pen/NyeQXd

```
body {
  display: flex;
}
.chart-wrap {
  flex: 1;
  flex-basis: 100%;
}
.chart {
  background: #efefef;
}

<div class="chart-wrap">
  <div class="chart"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: When the chart is resized its witdth and height are being set in addition to the viewBox attribute. Take out the width and height and it will scale appropriately.

Comment: @Mark only the width and height are being set on `resize`, the viewbox settings are set only once initially. The width/height of the SVG needs to be set so that it can grow as you stretch the window...

Comment: Add `min-width: 0` to `.chart-wrap`. https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zReOYb

Comment: You can set a max-width and/or min-width in your css to constrain the max/min svg dimensions, but you don't need those attributes set on your root svg node: https://codepen.io/psdpainter/pen/zReOXv.