# gwt datagrid Bootstrap Select cell (need to execute javascript after cell has been added/rendered)

Tags: select, gwt, datagrid, gwtbootstrap3

I inherited a project that uses GWT to create a web application. It uses a GWT wrapper for Bootstrap3 to do the styling of elements. This is working nicely for the most part. Now I hit a road block trying to add a Bootstrap3 [`Select`](http://gwtbootstrap3.github.io/gwtbootstrap3-demo/#select) to a GWT `DataGrid` table that currently uses a GWT [`SelectionCell`](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/cell/client/SelectionCell.html). The problem is that a `SelectionCell` is not 'Bootstrap styled' and therefore doesn't match the style of the rest of web application.

Unfortunately, I cannot simply add the `Select` to a GWT `DataGrid` as the `Select` does not implement the GWT `Cell` interface nor does it extend a class that can be added to a `Column` that is then added to the `DataGrid`. Sub classing `Select` and implementing `Cell` fixes this problem. However, I cannot get the `Select` to render properly as it requires a JavaScript function to be executed after the `Select` has been attached to the DOM which it never is being wrapped by a `Column` in a `DataGrid`.

Instead, it is rendered into a `SafeHtmlBuilder` by the `render` function of `Cell`.

```
// GWTBootstrap3::Select function to render the Select
public void render() {
    if (isAttached())
        command(getElement(), SelectCommand.RENDER);
}

protected native void command(Element e, String command) /*-{
    $wnd.jQuery(e).selectpicker(command);
}-*/;
```

Since the `Select` is never attached to the DOM I need to call the `selectpicker` function manually. For his, I created my own native function which I need to call after the `SafeHtmlBuilder` has been added to the `DataGrid`. If my `Select` subclass accepts `CLICK` events through `Cell`'s `onBrowserEvent` and calling the native function after clicking into the cell renders the `Select` properly.

What I cannot figure out is when to call the `selectpicker` function programatically to render the `Select` automatically after a row has been added by an RPC call. I tried to register different handlers to no avail. The handlers are called and my native function wrapping the `selectpicker` function is called as well but it seems like the HTML `select` has not yet been added to the table. Calling the above JavaScript snipped from the JavaScript console of a browser also works. So it should work find but I need to find the right place to call :(

Handlers in `DataGrid` that I am using:

- addLoadingStateChangeHandler
- addRowCountChangeHandler

I also tried to call it at different places after the calls to add to `DataGrid` the data have been made. Again, the HTML `select` doesn't seem to have been added to the `table`. ie. when I call the JavaScript snipped right after a call to `myListDataProviderObject.getList()addAll(my data)`.

Comment: Would not it be easier to simply add Bootstrap CSS styles to your existing cell?

Comment: The problem is that the HTML `select` is converted to something like this: `<div> <div>Text of select item</div> <ul> <li> item1 </li> <li> itme2 </li> </ul> <select style="display"><option> item 1</option> <option> item2 </option> </select> </div>

Comment: And why is this a problem? You can still apply any CSS styles you need to this HTML.

Comment: This is what I am doing as a fallback for now. However, adding the Bootstrap styles to the HTML `select` does not style the HTML `options` (which cannot be styled at the moment if I remember correctly). More importantly features of the Bootstrap `Select` like option groups and adding checkmarks will not work.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you need to add a [Scheduler call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12368316/gwt-timer-and-scheduler-classes/12371520#12371520) before calling your native method to make sure that the browser finished rendering the UI (e.g. your DataGrid) before this call is executed.

Comment: I tried to add a Scheduler as well as a Timer and got things working somewhat. Using a timer called from `DataGrid::redraw` renders the `Selects` after the data is added to the grid. Adding the Timer to the `render` function of my `Cell` implementation doesn't work even if I set the timeout of the timer to 20 seconds and the `select` is clearly added to the DOM . After selecting another drop-down the grid/cell is redrawn which removes the rendered select. I see my `render` method and the JS being called but the JS does not render the select. I stopped perssuing this for now.

Comment: Typically you use `refresh` on a DataProvider, not `redraw` on a DataGrid. Then you do not lose existing selections, etc.

Comment: `DataGrid::redraw` is manually called only after the initial data has been added and when the `DataGrid` is shown (the page uses multiple tabs each having its own `DataGrid`). If `redraw` is not called the page will only show the row header not the data.

Comment: I'll check the `DataProvider::refresh` function, thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: DataGrid in tabs is a different issue - sometimes it gets height of 0 when tabs are switched, which is done by changing their visibility. Typically, you need another Scheduler call :). Alternatively, if you can set height on your DataGrid, you won't need to redraw it.